# App Cordova não funciona como esperado

Tags: android, angularjs, apache-cordova, sdk, visual-studio-2015

Fiz um simples aplicativo utilizando *Apache Cordova* no *Visual Studio 2015*, e adicionei o *AngulaJS*.

Quando eu testo no *Riple* emulador funciona como esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então eu gero a *APK* para testar no smartphone físico, para isso eu uso o comando:

```
cordova build android --debug
```

Dentro do diretório do projeto, instalo a *apk* no aparelho:

> Sansumg Galaxy Ace - Android 3.2.6

Também alterei esta configuração `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="6" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />`, mas não funciona como esperado:

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Não sei o que está acontecendo, fico grato com qualquer ajuda.

Comment: aparentemente tem a ver com o arquivo do angular não ter sido localizado. Você pode verificar a localização do mesmo no arquivo index.html

Comment: Eu testei em um dispositivo com plataforma Android 5.1.1 e funcionou, acho que pode ser algo com a versão. O Angular esta referenciado corretamente pois funciona em alguns aparelhos. @RafaelMenaBarreto Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lendo neste link: [Apache Cordova Documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) a documentação do Cordova descobri que só funciona a partir da API 14.
:(
Mas obrigado pela ajuda.